# GCP Workflows - Redirect HTTP url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-redirect, google-workflows

I am calling an external API HTTP url which redirects 2-3 times.
Current pipeline has a Shell script which used `curl -L`. I am migrating it to GCP Workflows.

1. I haven't been able to find any param that lets me do the same for
   `http.get` call in GCP Workflows. Is that understanding correct?
2. Which means I have to put a loop around every API call in Workflows and look for response code. And keep on looping till I get a 2xx or reach max-redirects I am happy with (say 10). Seems odd to me as many APIs may not redirect today but may later, so I need to add this loop logic to any external API I call.
3. The only workaround (if needed), I can think of is creating a cloud function and use for e.g. the Python `requests` library with the arg `allow_redirects = True`

Comment: When you perform a Call with Cloud Workflow, you get a response. In that response, you have the body, but also the HTTP code. You can test it. If you have a 2XX, it's fine, if you have a redirect (301 302) get the redirect URL and perform another call. You can do that in loop.

Comment: Thanks, I should update the question. It is the only option I can think of doing it native in Workflows. I only wish there was a redirect param as that means if external API I call which doesn't redirect now but if it does get redirected in future, I would need to add this loop. Which means I should always do that for all API calls.

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/iteration#for-in-loop) ?

Comment: Thanks, I guess a loop as I mentioned in #2 in my question is only option native to workflows. I wise redirect management is added to the http connector.